In this situation git pull vs git rebase
I am a beginner git user. Please give me advice on the situation below.
1. Create a feature branch to implement functions in the develop branch.
2. Merge a new commit into the develop branch (this commit contains functionality associated with the feature branch created in 1.)
3. I would like to import the newly merged commit from the feature branch created in step 1 to develop. Would it be better to merge using git pull, or would it be better to use git rebase?
4. Of course, after completing work on the feature branch, you need to merge it back to develop.
I used git pull, but I'm worried that it might cause confusion due to the complicated log. Is this the right choice?

git pull is not normally what you use to merge branches, so it's unclear what's actually happening here. Could you show us the actual commands you ran?

@Schwern I just ran git pull origin develop. What you mean is that you generally use git merge rather than git pull?

I can't really follow what you did. You created the feature branch, but instead of using the feature branch you still developed on the develop branch?

The question shouldn't be "pull or rebase", but rather "merge or rebase". And this has been answered. ("pull" is more or less just "fetch + merge", but depending on configuration it might beven be "fetch + rebase")

@mammoth 1) Rather than describing each step, would you tell us the commands you ran at each step? That avoids any misunderstanding. 2) Also please show us git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all so we can see the true state of your repository (obscure the commit messages if you like). This also helps us understand.
